# Disable draggable for each element using :lt(3) Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

I have the following working code:

```
$stock.click(function () {
    $waste.append($stock.children('.container:lt(3)').card('upturn').droppable('disable').css( "left", function(i) {return ["0rem", "2rem", "4rem"][i];}) ); //3 divs
  });
```

This code adds several classes to 3 div's, except the for the css. Each div gets a different left property using:

```
.css( "left", function(i) {return ["0rem", "2rem", "4rem"][i];})
```

This all works, but I also want to disable the draggable option for the first 2 div's.

I've tried things like (1):

```
.draggable('disable', function(i) {return ["true", "true", "false"][i];})
```

and (2)

```
.draggable(function(i) {return ['disable', 'disable', 'enable'][i];})
```

but try (1) disables all the 3 divs, not just the first 2 and try (2) doesn't work at all.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **disabled** property of draggable widget is set with the **option** method and this property expects a Boolean, by other hand the **css** jQuery method accepts a function as a second parameter but the **disable** method or the **disabled** property not. The best approach is to use the **each** method to iterate on each item:

```
.each(function(i){ $(this).draggable("option", "disabled", [false, true, true, false][i]) });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/cLLpa06r/)